# Httpd cannot restart on Debian

Tags: linux, apache, debian

Good morning!

This morning i got a email from a college. He said that he can't restart httpd trough directadmin. Directadmin only gives : "An error has occurred".

I tried to search the logs and i found this in the errortaskq.log

> 2014:04:18-00:10:01: Unable to find the pid file: /var/run/httpd.pid
>
> 2014:04:18-00:11:42: Error restarting service httpd : uid 0 gid 0 : /etc/init.d/httpd restart                         >>/dev/null 2>>/dev/null

When i try to run

> sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart

I get

> Remaining processes: 2230 19413 19584 20328 23504 23505 23553 23636 24036 24063 24064
> Stopping httpd:
>
> Remaining processes: 2230 19413 19584 20328 23504 23505 23553 23636 24036 24063 24064
> Stopping httpd:
>
> Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
> (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
> no listening sockets available, shutting down
> Unable to open logs

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a little bit radical, but you could try to kill the httpd proccesses, and then restart it. It happens sometimes to me with php-cgi. A restart does not work, i have to kill the processes manually in order to be able to start it again.

Answer (score 0):

"Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80 (98)Address already in use " suggest that something all ready running 80 port. Find out which service is running on 80 port.

Comment: Well.. That's because HTTPD is still running. I can't stop HTTPD so it tries to restart but it can't because it is running

Comment: ps aux | grep -i httpd or  ps aux | grep -i apache. findout pid running process of apache & kill using kill -9 pid_apache process OR  pkill -9 apache OR pkill -9 httpd